# How can I include a multi part library with webpack?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I created a multi part library similar to the example from [webpack/webpack/.../multi-part-library](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/tree/master/examples/multi-part-library). In my apps I want to be able to import parts of my library like this:

```
ìmport Button from 'myLib/atoms/button';

// or

import { Button } from 'myLib/atoms';
```

My webpack configuration for the apps looks like this and I get an error (`Cannot resolve module 'myLib/atoms'` or `Cannot resolve module 'myLib/atoms/button'`):

```
module.exports = {
    'entry': {
        'app': './client.js',
    },
    'output': {
        'filename': 'bundle.js',
    },
    'externals': {
        'react': true,
        'react-dom': true,
        'myLib': true,
    },
    'module': {
        'loaders': [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel',
            },
        ]
    },
};
```

The webpack configuration for the library looks like this:

```
const files = glob.sync('**/*.js', {
    cwd: path.join(__dirname, 'atomic-design'),
    absolute: true,
});

let entries = {};

files.forEach((file) => {
    const name = path.basename(path.dirname(file));
    const newName = `atoms/${name}`;
    entries[newName] = file;
});

module.exports = {
    'entry': entries,
    'output': {
        'path': path.join(__dirname, 'lib'),
        'filename': 'myLib.[name].js',
        'library': ['myLib', '[name]'],
        'libraryTarget': 'umd',
        'umdNamedDefine': 'myLib',
    },
    'externals': {
        'react': true,
        'react-dom': true,
    },
    'module': {
        'loaders': [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel'
            },
        ]
    }
};
```

The files are structured like this:

```
- app
    - client.js
    - webpack.config.js
- myLib
    - webpack.config.js
    - atomic-design
        - button
            - index.js
        - text-field
            - index.js
```

So far I could only find tutorials for creating libraries with webpack, where they only use small examples of libraries.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Best regards,
JBrieske

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to add the paths (and adjust the `from 'path'` accordingly) for the modules you're trying to import to `resolve.modulesDirectories`.

Relevant documentation:  https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-modulesdirectories.

Bear in mind that [this will change in Webpack2](https://webpack.js.org/how-to/upgrade-from-webpack-1/), which is feature complete and is just short of documentation for a release.